# Is there a way to see when a php script last ran?

Tags: php

I am looking to make a script that runs and uses the time stamp of the last time it ran as a parameter to retrieve results that have been updated since that time. We were thinking of creating a database table and having it update that and then retrieve the date from there, but I was looking for any other approach that someone might suggest.

Comment: `touch` a `.lock` file? and then check its mtime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a database table to store the last run time is probably the easiest approach, especially if you already have that infrastructure in place. A nice thing about this method is that you can write the run time right before the script terminates, in case it runs for a long time and you do not want it to start up again too soon.

Alternatively you could either write a timestamp to file (which has it's own set of issues) or attempt to fish it out of a log file (for example, the web access log if the script is being run that way) but both of those seem harder.

Comment: Thanks Justin, good to know we were on the right track. I just wanted to make sure there wasn't something better out there.

Answer (score 0):

This might work: http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.fileatime.php (pass it $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'])

Comment: The problem with this would be if you edit the script or anything else accesses it, you will get an incorrect time.

Comment: Good point Alan; seems that many systems are disabling atime updates, too, for performance, so atime may not even be updated on all systems

Answer (score 0):

Your best result would be to store your last run time.  You could do this in a database if you need historical information, or you can just have a file that stores it.

Depending on how you run the script, you may be able to see it in your logs, but storing it yourself will be easier.